# unable to set background image according to resolution. multiple images coming in background

Tags: html, css

i want to show one image as a back ground. but it showing same image repeatedly.i want it should set if monitor resolution is high

```
<style>

        img
        {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 1363px;
        }
    </style>


    <body background="~/images/loginBG.jpg">
```

Answer (score 1):

Set

```
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

**see the difference**

```css
.wrepeat
        {
           background: url("https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/655066410087940096/QSUlrrlm.png");
             background-size:cover;
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
            height:800px;
        }
         .worepeat
        {
         background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg/488px-Small_Flag_of_the_United_Nations_ZP.svg.png");
            height:800px;
           
            
        }
```

```html
<html>
<body>

    <div class="wrepeat" ></div>
    
  

    <div class="worepeat" ></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: use background-image property instead

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use @media to add style for resolution that more than "1363px" and set that role to make the background cover all width:

```
@media (min-width: 1363px) {
  body {
    background-size: cover;
  }
}
```

also, add to this role to no-repeat the bg:

```
body {
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```